# How to convert propName: string: any in typescript in c# model?

Tags: c#, typescript

I have a class which implements an interface and both has this property in typescript

```
[propName: string]: any;
```

What does this mean in a class in typescript?
Why do we have brackets around the propName?
And how can I represent this propery in my c# model?

Comment: Your are looking for `indexers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[propName: string]` syntax means "any property name that is a string". It's basically a catch-all for any property name that might occur. You can read about it in the [Typescript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).

If you make a C# class that has all the other properties of the interface, tools like JSON.NET will ignore any extra properties present in the JSON object that are not present in the C# class. If you want to be sure to include all the properties in the interface you can use a `Dictionary<string, object>`, which behaves a bit like an object in Javascript, in regards to properties and values.

Answer (score 1):

Those are key string indexers.

You can represent it as `Dictionary<string, object>` or `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`